# Thinktecture Identity Server with OAuth Implicit Login

Tags: oauth, thinktecture-ident-server

I am trying to use javascript to login to identity server in OAuths Client. I can login and return to the return webpage successful.
I met a problem is why the Thinktecture identity sevrer always return '#' not '?' before parameters in querystring ,is that a bug?

the other question is how can I get the uses claims when I have access_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit flow uses a hash fragment not a query string - that is not a bug (check the OAuth2 spec).

The client does not consume the access token in OAuth2 - it is opaque to the client - the access token is meant to be used by the backend.

Comment: I can extract the access_token parameter with " location.hash.substring(1)" in javascript now. so is there anyway that I can get the user claims from Identity server if I have login?

Comment: I misread my answer - the token is not supposed to be consumed by the client. You cannot validate the signature on it. Send it to your API backend to validate - it can send you back the validated claims then.

Comment: may you give me more point to figure out which api I can send to identity server to validate this access_token? thanks.

Comment: You are supposed to validate the token in YOUR backend - not in identity server - that's the whole point of an access token.

Comment: got it,but is there any algorithm I can implement on my backend?

Comment: Use the standard JWT middleware that ships with Web API v2/Katana - e.g. like this https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer/blob/master/samples/Flows/ResourceServer%20(Web%20API%20v2)/Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

I write a javascript function with regular expression to extract the "access_token" parameter as below:

```
    var _access_token = getParameterByName('access_token');        
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        var str = location.hash.substring(1);
        var patt1 = new RegExp(name + "\\s*=\\s*([^&]+)", "g");
        var result = patt1.exec(str);;
        if (result == null)
            return "";
        else
            return result[1];
    }
```

then I try to use base64 to decode the access_token to get to extract the claims:

```
    var Claims = base64decode(access_token) 
    function base64decode(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    while (i < input.length) {

        enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

    }

    output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

    return output;

}
```